# ¿Cómo implementar un grafo según un contexto?

Tags: teoría-de-grafos

Hola la verdad no entiendo muy bien el problema quisiera saber si me podrían dar una mano.

Echando agua.
Tenemos tres contenedores cuyos tamaños son 10 pintas, 7 pintas y 4 pintas, respectivamente. Los recipientes de 7 y 4 pintas comienzan llenos de agua, pero el recipiente de 10 pintas está inicialmente vacío.
Se nos permite un tipo de operación: verter el contenido de un contenedor en otro, deteniéndose solo cuando el contenedor de origen está vacío o el contenedor de destino está lleno. Queremos saber si hay
 una secuencia de vertidos que deja exactamente 2 pintas en el recipiente de 7 o 4 pintas.

(a) Modele esto como un problema de gráfico: dé una definición precisa del gráfico involucrado y establezca la pregunta específica sobre este gráfico que necesita ser respondida.

(b) ¿Qué algoritmo se debe aplicar para resolver el problema?

(c) Encuentre la respuesta aplicando el algoritmo.

**He intentado lo siguiente
se que un vértice debe contener los tres contenedores en donde tengo esto como vértice inicial
<0,7,4> como nodo inicial, lo que hace referencia al contenedor 10 luego el 7 y por ultimo el 4, entonces siguiendo lo que dice el problema tengo estas posibilidades.**

**<0,7,4>,<10,0,1>,<10,7,0>,<7,0,4>,<4,7,0>**

Comment: Agrega lo que hayas investigado o intentado por favor

Comment: @BetaM he intentado lo siguiente
se que un vértice debe contener los tres contenedores en donde tengo esto como vértice inicial
<0,7,4> como nodo inicial, lo que hace referencia al contenedor 10 luego el 7 y por ultimo el 4, entonces siguiendo lo que dice el problema tengo estas posibilidades

<0,7,4>
<10,0,1>
<10,7,0>
<7,0,4>
<4,7,0>

Comment: Agregalo a tu pregunta por favor

Comment: @betaM ya lo hice, la verdad es lo único que entiendo pero no encuentro forma de como construir el grafo.